# Test cases with varying parameters

Tags: manual-testing, test-design

The test cases that were developed in the past were very high level (basically a summary and no steps) and I am now working on making them more detailed.  Many of them have multiple parameters under one test case, such as "verify that that these types of order (ABC, DEF, GHI) do not have the Cancel button available".  What is the proper way to set this up?  Three separate test cases, or one test case to be executed 3 times with differing parameters?

Comment: You should be able to get lot of very good resources to read regarding this subject.